# What kind of flags should be raised in the following cases?

Tags: discussion, flagging

Consider the following two cases:

1. The question asked shows no research effort. It could have been easily solved with minimum research from the side of the user who is asking. But it does not belong to homework-and-exercises tag.
2. The question is unrealistic, that is, it does  asks about something that is not feasible in reality, though the question asked is in Physics, and not "too broad", as it does not raise any good discussions.

Which type of flagging should be done for these two cases? In the first case, I could not flag as it does not belong to "Homework problems should ask for...." flag.  In the second case, I raised a moderator intervention flag, stating the question is unrealistic, but it was denied.

***A request: any moderator or person with high reputation, who can peep into my account and find about which flags I'm talking of, please don't mention it here to avoid unnecessary discussion. If you find out about what I'm talking here (which, of course, you will), please keep it to yourself; rather let's discuss the cases that I've mentioned here.***

Comment: Your last paragraph is unnecessary: no mod would disclose those details (which are not available to regular users, regardless of their reputation).

Comment: For #2, I'd think the non-mainstream policy would apply.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1. The question asked shows no research effort. It could have been easily solved with minimum research from the side of the user who is asking. But it does not belong to homework-and-exercises tag.

Whether the question deserves the [homework-and-exercises](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework-and-exercises) tag has *nothing* to do with whether it should be flagged or closed. So let's leave the tag out of this.

The first thing I would do to such a question is **downvote it**. This is literally what question downvotes were made for. It says so right in the tooltip you get if you hover over the down arrow.

Beyond that, what you should be thinking about is whether the question qualifies for the homework-like *close reason*, which is explained in our [homework-like question policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714). (Keep in mind that this policy applies to more than *just* homework questions.) Failure to do basic research qualifies as a lack of effort, which is one of the criteria by which a homework-like question can be closed. So if the question is homework-like and the asker has not done basic research, you can flag it for closure (using the standard flag) on that basis.

If the question is *not* homework-like, we do not have a standard close reason that would apply to it for not showing effort. Maybe we should, and maybe we will in the future. Depending on your reputation, you may be able to cast a close vote with a custom reason, in which you could mention the lack of effort. Otherwise, you should probably just downvote it.

> The question is unrealistic, that is, it does asks about something that is not feasible in reality, though the question asked is in Physics, and not "too broad", as it does not raise any good discussions.

Discussions? Remember, we *do not* want *discussions* on the main site. We want questions which can be answered.

Anyway, this type of question will likely fall under our policy against non-mainstream physics questions (which specifically includes any questions about fictional physics in a fictional universe). There is an associated close reason, which you should choose when flagging or voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

If the post contains inappropriate material, flag for mod attention. If there is nothing inappropriate, and you really don't know what flag to use, just leave a comment explaining why the question is off-topic and move on. Or don't leave a comment at all. No need to flag everything you deem off-topic all the time.

Also, a declined flag is no bid deal. Don't worry about it.

Comment: This kinda leaves out the off-topic flag for under-3k-rep users, which may or may not apply to point 2.

Comment: The questions I'm talking of are not inappropriate as such, but are unrealistic, as I've mentioned. Anyways, I'll take your advise.